# Problem occur while calling data from cloud function "Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':."

Tags: typescript, flutter, function, dart, cloud

I'm trying to retrieve data "classCode" from cloud function but every I get runtime error which said
**Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.**
Here is my code below:

```
  Future checkDetails({
    @required String classCode,
    @required String email,
    @required String password,
    @required UserType userType,
  }) async {
    await sharedPreferencesHelper.clearAllData();
    //Check if the School code is present and return "School not Present" if not
    //Then check if the user credentials are in the database or not
    //if not then return "Student Not Found" else return "Logging in"

    //Api Call to check details
    bool isClassPresent = false;
    bool isUserAvailable = false;
    String loginType = userType == UserType.STUDENT
        ? "Student"
        : userType == UserType.TEACHER ? "Parent-Teacher" : "Parent-Teacher";

    DocumentReference _classLoginRef =
        classRef.collection(classCode.toUpperCase().trim()).doc('Login');
  await _classLoginRef
        .get().then((onValue) {
      isClassPresent = onValue.exists;
      print("Inside Then :" + onValue.data.toString());
    });

    if (!isClassPresent) {
      print('Class Not Found');
      return ReturnType.CLASSCODEERROR;
    } else {
      print('Class Found');
    }

    CollectionReference _userRef = _classLoginRef.collection(loginType);
```

***Note:*** I'm using Typescript and I'm the beginner in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Would you change like below and try again?

Before

```
...
print("Inside Then :" + onValue.data.toString());
...
```

After

```
...
print("Inside Then :" + onValue.data().toString());
...
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. It changed from Inside Then: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.    to    Inside Then :null. Please help.